# Cakephp, save data from datatable

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table that im adding some data:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('CabFactura'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Agregar Factura'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id_agencia', array('default'=>'111','type'=>'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('dosificacion_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('nro_doc', array('type'=>'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('fecha', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY'));
    echo $this->Form->input('nit');
    echo $this->Form->input('anombre');
    echo $this->Form->input('total');
    echo $this->Form->input('cod_control', array('type'=>'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('estado', array('type'=>'hidden', 'default' => 'V'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cliente_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('vendedor_id');
?>
</fieldset>
<button id="agregar" class="button" type="button">Agregar Articulo</button>
<button id="eliminar" class="button" type="button">Eliminar Articulo</button>
<div id="det_tabla">
    <h2><?php echo __('Detalle Factura'); ?></h2>
    <table id ="tabla1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th class = "cal">Monto</th>
        <th>Nro. Lote</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
    </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Guardar/Imprimir')); ?>
```

Controller Add function:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->CabFactura->create();
        $this->DetFactura->create();

        $dosificaciones = $this->Dosificacion->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Dosificacion.estado = "Activo"'), 'order'=>'Dosificacion.id DESC'));
        $numero_autorizacion = $dosificaciones['Dosificacion']['nro_aut'];
        $numero_factura = $this->request->data['CabFactura']['nro_doc'];
        $nit_cliente = $this->request->data['CabFactura']['nit'];
        $fecha_compra['CabFactura']['fecha'] = $this->request->data['CabFactura']['fecha'];
        $fecha_compra['CabFactura']['fecha'] = date("Ydm", strtotime((string)$this->request->data['CabFactura']['nro_doc']));   
        $monto_compra = $this->request->data['CabFactura']['total'];
        $clave = $dosificaciones['Dosificacion']['llave'];
        //debug($clave);            
        $SimpleHtmlDom = new CodigoControlV7();
        $html = $SimpleHtmlDom->generar($numero_autorizacion, $numero_factura, $nit_cliente, $fecha_compra['CabFactura']['fecha'], $monto_compra, $clave);
        $this->request->data['CabFactura']['cod_control'] = $html;
        if ($this->CabFactura->save($this->request->data)) 
        {           
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The cab factura has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The cab factura could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }           

    }

    $dosi_id = $this->Dosificacion->CabFactura->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Dosificacion.id = CabFactura.dosificacion_id', 'Dosificacion.estado = "Activo"'), 'order'=>'nro_doc DESC', 'fields'=>'nro_doc'));
    if(!empty($dosi_id))
    {
        $this->request->data['CabFactura']['nro_doc'] = $dosi_id['CabFactura']['nro_doc']+1;
        //debug($dosi_id['CabFactura']['nro_doc']+1);
    }
    else
    {       
        $this->request->data['CabFactura']['nro_doc'] = 1;
    }
    $dosificacions = $this->CabFactura->Dosificacion->find('list');
    $clientes = $this->CabFactura->Cliente->find('list');
    $vendedors = $this->CabFactura->Vendedor->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('dosificacions', 'clientes', 'vendedors'));
}
```

If I have a submit button, I want all the data from my table save in my database.
I dunno how can I pass al my data to my controller on the add function.
Can you help me please.

Comment: You say you "have a submit button" but I don't see it :/

Comment: I'd recommend completing the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html). After that, you'll have the knowledge to do what you're asking.

Comment: ok now I explain more, srry. I now the dynamic for add data from diferent models, but in this case Im using datatable and my issue is to pass the data from the table.

Comment: please share your controller-> action

Comment: shared only my add function, I dunno where pass my det_table to my add function to add the data. thats my isuue :/